# CSS - IE 7 z-index problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, z-index

Good day to all. I have a dropdown menu (a div actually with display:none at onclick event on the searchbar it appears) placed inside a div with the following style:

```
background-image: url("/whatever.png");
height: 80px;
position: relative;
top: 60px;
width: 100%;
```

The div that appears (the dropdown) has:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid;
height: 185px;
left: 140px;
padding-top: 3px;
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
width: 134px;
z-index: 25;
```

Now... here is the problem (I had to hide some elements sorry about that also I can not provide an online copy sorry about that too):

[image]

The red line is a div on the same level as the container of the dropdown with style:

```
top: 140px;
width: 100%;
```

The blue bar (is a div placed inside 2 other divs with position: relative and float: left, nothing else) has:

```
background: url("blue.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #00FF00;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 22px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding-top: 5px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 210px;
```

This only occurs on IE 7 and 6. Is ok on all other browsers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `z-index: 50;` to the parent (container) div.

Comment: I already tried that... it isn't working. I mean... it solves the red line problem... but the blue bar still is on top.

Comment: Is the blue bar supposed to be on the drop down?

Comment: Give it a `z-index` of 20, then.